# Bootstrap template with off-canvas nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

This is not a coding question but rather a quick stop for directions.

I am looking into using Bootstrap framework for my next project. Bootstrap 3 official site has a great selection of default templates, but it seems to me they all have the same flaw -- I'll explain below.

One of the best responsive design features if a combination of JS and CSS media queries to take a regular, across the top, navigation and turn it into a hidden (on click) expand/collapse menus. This is great, BUT, all of the examples simply drop the menu links below each other and while it looks OK on a phone, it looks a bit ridiculous when a link with a single word, for example "About", is placed in a div of its own 768px wide.

A much nicer solution is to have that left or right sliding menu bar that pushes or overlaps the content of the site. Unfortunately there are not too menu of such examples, or at least I was not able to locate them.

This is where I need some help -- any basic templates with preferably right side menu on for smaller viewport browsers?

Comment: JASNY's Bootstrap fork has those templates. See Examples>Off Canvas Push Menu http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Oh, this is nice. Thanks. Will it be compatible with future bootstrap releases?

Comment: Can't say. He seems to update it regularly as v.3 has progressed (although it has not yet been updated for 3.1)

Comment: I know this is late to the game, but I just created what you are looking for http://webedge.github.io/Bootstrap-3.1.1-OffCanvasMenu/

Comment: @Jon Harding -- Not late at all. Looks great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example right off-canvas navbar that may work for you...

Most of the off-canvas examples I've found push a sidebar off-canvas, but the top navbar is still collapsed into the usual vertical nav.

However, this example adjusts the navbar into a sliding right sidebar on smaller devices:

https://codeply.com/p/KDMFdhc6c8 (Bootstrap 3.x)

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider switching over to Foundation (I've use bootstrap and foundation frameworks for several years and bout area great, one usually fits a project better than the other, depending on the needs).. Foundation has a native off-canvas component and it works very well (both left and right side off-canvas is available!)

foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html